« Et mèche » : sens; Bagatelle pour un massacre, Louis-Ferdinand Céline
Tiré de Bagatelle pour un Massacre, Céline

Pour parler franc, là entre nous, je finis encore plus
mal que j’ai commencé… Oh ! j’ai pas très bien
commencé… je suis né, je le répète, à Courbevoie,
Seine… je le répète pour la millième fois… après bien
des aller et retour je termine vraiment au plus mal… y
a l’âge, vous me direz… y a l’âge !… c’est entendu !…
à 63 ans et mèche, il devient extrêmement ardu de se
refaire une situation…

Le TLFi adonne la définition suivante pour « mèche ».

(TLFi) B.  − Pop. Il n'y a pas (plus) mèche et, p. ell., pas mèche! Il n'y a pas moyen, c'est impossible.

Toujours farceur comme à son ordinaire, papa Dufailli; il n'y a pas mèche à lui refuser: allons! vite, vite! entrez (Vidocq,Mém., t.2, 1828-29, p.96).
Rien à faire de cette femme-là (...). Pas mèche (...). La voie est barrée (A. Daudet, Rois en exil,1879, p.184).

Rem. On dit aussi plus rarement il y a mèche. Il y a possibilité. Et quand y aurait-il mèche à toucher cette bonne galette-là? (Verlaine, Corresp., t.3, 1895, p.119).

On pourrait s'attendre à « il n'y a plus mèche » ou » pas mèche », selon la possibilité d'une ellipse. Est-ce qu'il s'agit d'un degré de plus d'ellipse ? Mais comment concilier ce « et » avec « à 63 ans » ? Comment comprendre ce « mèche » ? Est-ce possible que cela signifie « mèche blanche » au lieu de quelque chose comme ce qui vient d'être  envisagé ?

"63 ans et mèche", sans regarder aucun dictionnaire, dans ce contexte, est-ce que tu peux deviner ce que ça pourrait vouloir dire? Il n'y a qu'une seule possibilité...

@LPH Il manque un tiret entre "Louis" et "Ferdinand" dans "Louis-Ferdinand Céline".

@Frank Je n'ai pas mis +1 à ton commentaire que je trouve un tantinet malveillant. Un non francophone ne peut pas penser à l'expression à des poussières s'il ne l'a jamais entendue auparavant.

@Frank On peut, possiblement, deviner, oui, mais le FSE n'est pas un site de devinettes, c'est un site où on établit, où on asserte l'exactitude (ou la fausseté) de propositions concernant la  linguistique  du français.

63 ans et {quelques | quelque chose | un chouia | un pou-ième}. Toutes ces variantes sont familières, et mèche est argotique.

Au départ mèche exprimait demi(e) ajouté à un entier :

Ce qu'il y a ? Y a que ce matin à quatre plombes et mèche, Guigne-à-gauche a craché dans le sac, place de la Roquette... et que j'y étais ! (ᴏꜱᴄᴀʀ ᴍᴇ́ᴛᴇ́ɴɪᴇʀ, En famille, 1885)

Ce sens viendrait d'après certains (voir par exemple) de l'italien mezzo mais ceci est mis en doute par le Dictionnaire Historique en langue Française qui signale que Wartburg le rattache à mèche pris au sens de matière préparée pour prendre feu.
Jacques Cellard dans son Dictionnaire du français non conventionnel signale que ce sens de « demi » est vieilli et que depuis environ 1930  la valeur du mot est oubliée, et mèche signifie plus généralement ce qui vient en surcroit d'un compte, l'excédent, ce qui dépasse, comme la mèche d'une lampe à pétrole. Il ajoute que toutefois il est parfois difficile de décider si l'expression doit être prise au sens strict ou au sens large et il cite un exemple tiré de Céline (Nord, 1960).

Oh, oui, me dis-je, bientôt tout sera terminé... ouf !... assez nous avons
vu... à soixante-cinq ans et mèche que peut bien vous foutre la plus pire
archibombe H ?...

Bagatelle pour un massacre a été publié en 1937, les deux interprétations pourraient être possibles à mon avis :  « 63 ans et demi » ou « un peu plus de 63 ans ».
De toutes façons je soupçonne que peu de francophones connaissent l'expression de nos jours et quand il lit « 63 ans et mèche » un francophone substituera plus ou moins spontanément « poussière » à « mèche », le sens étant exactement le même.

− Loc. fam. [En parlant de ce qui peut se comptabiliser, en partic. d'une somme d'argent ou de l'âge de qqn] Et des poussières. Et un peu plus. Il a quarante ans et des poussières. 33 briques et des poussières.  (TLF)


C'est une définition qui semble manquer au TLFi ; c'est un terme argotique ou simplement populaire ? En tout cas c'est une définition qui explique parfaitement les mots de Céline.

@LPH Le TLF  n'est pas la seule référence, et en matière de langue il n'existe aucune bible en ce domaine. Il **ne peut pas ** exister de bible. Je dirais que c'est argotique (cf mes ref dans la réponse)

Non, je suis d'accord il n'y a pas de référence universelle, mais vous conviendrez avec moi que le TLFi les surpasse tous ; il est bien connu que le Wiktionnaire (très poussé) fait continuellement référence au TLFi, et il utilise même ses définitions.

@None J'ai tout de suite pensé à l'occitan mièg (prononcé "miètch*), mais bon, Courbevoie, c'est loin de l'Occitanie.

@jlliagre Oui, cité aussi par Cellard, le DHLF de son côté cite le provençal mech, des cousins de mezzo.

@LPH Si le wiktionnaire fait continuellement référence aux définitions du TLF c'est parce que ce dernier le permet juridiquement, ce qui n'est cas pour la majorité des dictionnaires dont le copyright l'interdit. Par contre le Wiktionnaire, qui peut être mis à jour (alors que ce n'est pas le cas du TLF depuis 1994) peut refléter une langue plus récente. Par contre une entrée du wiktionnaire peut contenir des erreurs, souvent involontaires quand ce sont des typos, ou présenter des lacunes (quand le contributeur ne donne pas tous les sens d'un mot).
